# Canvas RuleLines With grid UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, canvas, uwp

I'm working in a program which contains a canvas ,
This canvas includes some shapes and RuleLines ,
I added a grid to the canvas and it looked like this 
[image]

the problem is the program is not smooth when I Manipulate or Zoom  this canvas,

this is the Grid code in C# :

```
   public void GridPartitions (Grid grid)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 50; ii++)
            {
                MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(20) });
                MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(20) });
            }
            for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
            {
                for(int coulmn = 0; coulmn < 50; coulmn++)
                {
                    var PartitionRectangle = new Rectangle();
                    PartitionRectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush() { Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0) };
                    PartitionRectangle.StrokeThickness = 0.2;
                    grid.Children.Add(PartitionRectangle);
                    Grid.SetRow(PartitionRectangle, row);
                    Grid.SetColumn(PartitionRectangle, coulmn);
                }
            }
        }
```

However in Microsoft OneNote UWP 
it has this option and it runs very smooth whatever the the number of the RuleLines and looks like this :
[image]

Any ideas to Improve My Code ?

Thank You.

Comment: Try putting the lines directly in the Canvas instead of a Grid. A Grid with 50x50 cells might not be so performant when it comes to laying out its children.

Comment: I tried that , there was a noticeable difference but still not smooth and fluid , as long as the canvas size is changing and I wanted the grid to fill This Canvas ,I used ObservableCollection<Line> , and I've Bind it with ItemsControl inside the Canvas , now I'm working on running the CanvasSizeChanged event handler inside a thread  .. I hope It will Work

Comment: Could you please share a demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Ok when I'll optimize this code I'll share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the final code 
working perfect
smooth and adaptive ,the background grids are updating according to the Canvas size change
I added two borders 
the background is LinearGradientBrush for each border ,,........
enough talking and here is the Code:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="BorderScrollViewer" ZoomMode="Enabled" ZoomSnapPointsType="Mandatory"
              HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              ManipulationDelta="MyCanvas01_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All">



        <Canvas Name="MyCanvas01" Background="White"  
                                        MinWidth="1200" MinHeight="720"
                    Width="1200" Height="720"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                    ManipulationDelta="MyCanvas01_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" 
                    SizeChanged="MyCanvas01_SizeChanged"
                     >

            <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas01,Path=Width}" 
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas01,Path=Height}">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="25,0" SpreadMethod="Repeat" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="-25,0">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.53"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.48"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF320064" Offset="0.49"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF320061" Offset="0.51"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF320068" Offset="0.51"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
            <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas01,Path=Width}" 
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas01,Path=Height}" >
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,25" SpreadMethod="Repeat" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,-25">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.53"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.48"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF320064" Offset="0.49"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF320061" Offset="0.51"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF320068" Offset="0.51"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>

            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="TT01" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>

        </Canvas>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is My new Code .. Its better But still not smooth 
I tried to Make everything in OOP as much as possible 
XAML:

```
<Canvas Name="MyCanvas01" Background="Transparent"  
                                    MinWidth="2500" MinHeight="720"
                Width="2500" Height="720"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                ManipulationDelta="MyCanvas01_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" 
                SizeChanged="MyCanvas01_SizeChanged">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind HorizontalLines}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}"
                      X2="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas01, Path=Width}" Y2="{Binding To.Y}"
                      Stroke="black" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind VerticalLines}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}"
                      X2="{Binding To.X }" Y2="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas01, Path=Height}"
                      Stroke="black" StrokeThickness="0.5"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="st01"/>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="TT01" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>

        </Canvas>
```

C#:

```
public  void  DrawMissingLines(ObservableCollection<LineBindingPointsClass> lines, double missingLines, Point from, Point to ,int gg)
        {
            if (missingLines > 0)
            {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < missingLines; ii++)
                {

                    lines.Add(new LineBindingPointsClass() { From = from , To = to });
                    if (gg == 1)
                    {
                        from.X += 25;
                        to.X += 25;
                    }
                    else if (gg == 2)
                    {
                        from.Y += 25;
                        to.Y += 25;
                    }

                }
            }
            else if (missingLines < 0)
            {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < -missingLines; ii++)
                {                    
                        lines.Remove(lines.Last());                    
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
private void MyCanvas01_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas SizedCanvas = (Canvas)sender;
            double missingVerticalLines, MissingHorizontalLines;

            missingVerticalLines = (Math.Floor(SizedCanvas.Width) -  VerticalLines.Count() * 25 ) / 25;
            MissingHorizontalLines = (Math.Floor(SizedCanvas.Height) - HorizontalLines.Count() * 25) / 25;
            DrawMissingLines(VerticalLines, missingVerticalLines, 
                new Point(VerticalLines.Count()*25  , 0),
                new Point(VerticalLines.Count() * 25 , SizedCanvas.Height ),1);

            DrawMissingLines(HorizontalLines, MissingHorizontalLines
                , new Point(0,HorizontalLines.Count() * 25 ),                
                new Point( SizedCanvas.Width, HorizontalLines.Count() * 25) ,2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For smooth zooming and Support gestures and (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + MouseWheel) you can put the canvas inside ScrollViewer.
Here is example Code:

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" ZoomSnapPointsType="Mandatory"> 
     <Canvas Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
            ManipulationDelta="MyCanvas_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All" CacheMode="BitmapCache">   

        <Rectangle Width="500" Height="500" Fill="Black"/>
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

actually its very smooth
Now I'm working on adding adaptive Grid